# Cannot break small payroll system in different methods

Tags: java

I want to start by saying that I'm a newby in Java, and it's also my first time asking something on this site. After 3 days trying to figure out how to break this small program in methods, I haven't been able to do so. could anyone help me with it ?

I've been reading and it looks like I'm violating the single responsibility principle. Any opinions would be more than welcome.

```
public class RateSystem {

    double employeeSalary;

    public int salaryRate(String employeePosition) {

        if (employeePosition.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            return 40;
        } else if (employeePosition.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
            return 30;
        } else
            employeePosition.equalsIgnoreCase("3");

        return 50;

    }

}
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Employee position please...");

        System.out.println("Press 1 for IT " + "\n" + "Press 2 for Tech" + 
                           "\n" + "Press 3 for engineer");

        String ePosition = input.nextLine();
        RateSystem raul = new RateSystem();
        int getPay = raul.salaryRate(ePosition);

        System.out.println("How many hours did he work for the week?...");
        int weekHours = input.nextInt();

        int totalPay = 0;
        if (weekHours <= 40) {
            totalPay = getPay * weekHours;

            System.out.println("Employee salary is " + totalPay);
        } else {

            int overTimeHours = weekHours - 40;
            int extra$$PerOverTime = overTimeHours * getPay +(overTimeHours * getPay/2);

            totalPay = getPay * (weekHours - overTimeHours);

            System.out.println("The employee accumulated 40 hours equivalent to $"+ 
totalPay + " plus $" + extra$$PerOverTime + " overtime hours, a total of $"+(extra$$PerOverTime + totalPay));


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please note that these kinds of questions (where you have working code) should go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If we are looking at `main()`, It does multiple tasks:

1. Receive user input
2. Calculate total pay and possible other finance information
3. Print the results

How's that for starters

Answer (score 0):

I see followings could be added.

1) Salaries are created for Employees so why don't you create and Employee class and encapsulate details inside it like "employeePosition". So you can add more things later and having setters inside it you will get the chance of changing setter logics for employees.

2) You can create a Calculator class and create methods accepting single Employee or a List of Employees and calculate their Salary Rates.

3) You also can add a Printing related class. So you can produce different printing for single or List of Employees or may be like a tabular format.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified following methods in your code.

1) showMainMenu  --> responsible to show menu to the user

2) readMenuSelection --> here you will read whatever user has selected in the main menu. It should be read in int value rather than string.

3) For each Selection from menu there will be separate methods such as payForIT(), payForTech() and payForEngineer()

Comment: why not have 3 classes for the positions (with a common super class or interface) and each will have a `calcPay()`.  This way you get better support for future postions

Comment: Well you can make it as reusable as you want by introducing interfaces but as he stated that he just started java coding and by looking at the code I can easily pick that the problem is more about  creating methods having single responsibility.

Comment: I like your idea. In fact now that you mentioned makes sense. I remember I was watching a video on Udemy and sounds about something I should be able to do. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Employee position please...");

        System.out.println("Press 1 for IT " + "\n" + "Press 2 for Tech" + "\n" + "Press 3 for engineer");

        String position = input.nextLine();
        RateSystem rateSystem = new RateSystem();
        rateSystem.setEmployeePosition(position);

        System.out.println("How many hours did he work for the week?...");
        int weekHours = input.nextInt();
        rateSystem.setWeekHours(weekHours);

        rateSystem.calculateSalary();

        int totalPay = rateSystem.getTotalPay();
        int overTime = rateSystem.getOvertime();

        if (overTime > 0) {
            System.out.println("The employee accumulated 40 hours equivalent to $" + totalPay + " plus $" + overTime
                    + " overtime hours, a total of $" + (overTime + totalPay));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Employee salary is " + totalPay);
        }

    }

}



public class RateSystem {

    private final int STANDARD_WORK = 40;

    private double employeeSalary;

    private int weekHours;

    private Position employeePosition;

    private int totalPay = 0;

    private int overTime = 0;

    public void setEmployeePosition(String position) {
        employeePosition = Position.fromString(position);
    }

    public void setWeekHours(int weekHours) {
        this.weekHours = weekHours;
    }

    public int getTotalPay() {
        return totalPay;
    }

    public int getOvertime() {
        return overTime;
    }

    public void calculateSalary() {
        int salaryRate = employeePosition.getRate();

        int workhours = (weekHours > STANDARD_WORK) ? STANDARD_WORK : weekHours;
        int overTimeHours = (weekHours > STANDARD_WORK) ? (weekHours - STANDARD_WORK) : 0;

        totalPay = workhours * weekHours;

        overTime = (overTimeHours * salaryRate) + (overTimeHours * salaryRate / 2);
    }
}



public enum Position {
    IT(40), Tech(30), Engineer(50);

    private int rate = 0;

    Position(int r) {
        rate = r;
    }

    public int getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public static Position fromString(String position) {
        switch (position) {
        case "1":
            return IT;
        case "2":
            return Tech;
        case "3":
            return Engineer;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To follow single responsibility principle you have to create method for each common task in your program. That helps do not repeat code and helps to modify code in one place.

I have created separate methods for building string and for printing string as you use it frequently in your code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        println("Employee position please...");

        println(buildString("Press 1 for IT ", "\n", "Press 2 for Tech", "\n", "Press 3 for engineer"));

        String ePosition = input.nextLine();
        RateSystem raul = new RateSystem();
        int getPay = raul.salaryRate(ePosition);

        println("How many hours did he work for the week?...");
        int weekHours = input.nextInt();

        int totalPay = 0;
        if (weekHours <= 40) {
            totalPay = getPay * weekHours;

            println(buildString("Employee salary is ", String.valueOf(totalPay)));
        } else {

            int overTimeHours = weekHours - 40;
            int extra$$PerOverTime = overTimeHours * getPay + (overTimeHours * getPay / 2);

            totalPay = getPay * (weekHours - overTimeHours);

            println(buildString("The employee accumulated 40 hours equivalent to $", String.valueOf(totalPay),
                    " plus $", String.valueOf(extra$$PerOverTime), " overtime hours, a total of $",
                    String.valueOf((extra$$PerOverTime + totalPay))));

        }

    }

    private static String buildString(String... strings) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String string : strings) {
            builder.append(string);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    private static void println(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

And class `RateSystem`:

```
package com.stackoverflow.main;

public class RateSystem {

    double employeeSalary;

    public int salaryRate(String employeePosition) {

        if (equalsIgnoreCase(employeePosition, "1")) {
            return 40;
        } else if (equalsIgnoreCase(employeePosition, "2")) {
            return 30;
        } else if (equalsIgnoreCase(employeePosition, "3"))
            return 50;
        return 0;
    }

    private boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String arg1, String arg2) {
        return arg1.equalsIgnoreCase(arg2);
    }
}
```

Comment: so instead of `System.out.println` you call `println` repeatedly. how is that better??

Comment: In this case it doesn't help but it shows the principle.

Comment: an extremely poor example. more confusing than clarifying

Comment: How can you apply single responsibility principle in this example?

Comment: a better example would be to send a String to a method that is responsible to printing it into any given PrintStream, with a default of `System.out`

Comment: see other answers here that give better examples, in my opinion

Comment: I really appreciate all your comment guys. I'll take some this ideas and start from scratch. I knew it was wrong, but I needed to finish my idea before starting to improve my code design.